# What happens to changed files when I switch Git branches?

Tags: git, sh

In spite of using Git for quite some time, I still fail to understand its branching mechanics. In particular, consider a new project `foo` with a single file `bar.txt` initialized by these simple commands:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ cd foo
$ git init
$ touch bar.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'Initial commit'
```

Now when I create a branch `foobar`, `git branch` shows that I'm still on `master`:

```
$ git branch foobar
$ git branch
  foobar
* master
```

But when I make change to the file `bar.txt`:

```
$ echo quux >> quux.txt
$ git status
modified: quux.txt
```

Then when I checkout the other branch, I can see that the file `bar.txt` has been modified also there:

```
$ git checkout foobar
$ git status
modified: quux.txt
```

I already know that this behavior allows me to choose to which branch do I want to commit my changes, but I find it annoying. I suspect that I fail to understand the basic idea behind Git branching. Is there a way to tell git that when I make changes to `master`, I don't want them to be visible from any other branch which I may choose to checkout?

Comment: If you want to cripple git this way, do it by always committing before switching branches, and then reset the tip on checkout if that got you a WIP commit.

Comment: My question is, why would I cripple git by this? Why is it such a great idea that changes I make while in branch `a` are available when I checkout branch `b`. What is this a desirable feature?

Comment: Because what needs doing and what branch it should be committed on are two separate concerns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The changes you make in the working directory aren't a part of any branch until you commit them. So where you've gone wrong is in thinking that when you checkout a branch and then modify a file, you've made a modification "on the branch". You haven't done that, you've modified the working directory.

So you have a dirty working directory based on one branch and you checkout another branch - the uncommitted changes stay in the working directory because otherwise they'd not be saved *anywhere*. You wouldn't be able to checkout the first branch again and have the local changes reappear.

What you probably want to do is `git stash` before you switch branches. This saves local changes to a temporary branch, which you can get back to later with `git stash pop`.

Comment: Is `git stash pop` a synonym of `git stash apply`?

Comment: No; `git stash pop` simply discards the top item of the `stash`. You can think of `git stash drop`, however, as `git stash apply` + `git stash pop` (if the apply succeeds).

Comment: I think it's the other way: `pop` = `apply` + `drop`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stash` to store staged/uncommited changes:

```
git stash
```

Now you can switch branch with a fresh working directory:

```
git branch master
git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

To apply your stashed changes:

```
git branch foobar
git stash apply
```

Comment: When I do `git stash`, do newly created / deleted files also get stashed (uncreated / undeleted)?

Comment: That works with --include-untracked but you need to pay attention to not miss this. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash (save)

Comment: @BorisStitnicky Yup, they do! They `git stash apply --index` to get the same raw output from these commands.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you are not allowed to switch branches if the checkout affects files that are `dirty`. In your case the modification to the file is not affecting a checkout of foobar. If there were changes in the locally modified file of the branch to be checked out, the checkout would abort. There is no such concept of keeping modified files for a single branch when switching branches. If you don't want to have these local modifications when checking out `foobar`, you have the following possibilities:

- `stash save` your changes and clear your local modifications. This allows to reapply the changes when you switch back to master. (`git stash save --include-untracked` to also capture new and not yet staged files)
- `reset --hard` your current branch to `HEAD` before checking out (which discards the changes of course)
- `checkout -f foobar` to also discard the local changes (same effect as resetting).