# A little confusion about the VS.code UX and git checkout

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am not a day-to-day programmer so get a little rusty with stuff now and again. I understand GIT, etc but the behavior and UX of VS.Code when using it is not clear to me.

Specifically, when I issue a "git checkout " command from the terminal, GIT responds as I would expect (in the Terminal) and confirms the change of branch. However, the VS.Code toolbar (bottom left) doesn't change and I remain in the original branch. If I exit VS.Code and run it again then I DO see the right (checked out) branch in the toolbar. Is that expected? Is the UX not responsive to a checkout?

At a broader level, what is the general workflow for changing branches within VS.Code. For example, if I have a file open BranchA is checked out and then checkout BranchB (where that file is different) then VS.Code doesn't show any change. I assume that is by design but I could also imagine getting into a bit of a pickle with what the UI shows vs. the branch and files GIT is changing.

I have searched and found a few other folks who seem to have similar confusion so hoping that there is perhaps some docs somewhere that perhaps describe the recommended workflow here.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure to install the [GitLens plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens)

It does come with a [branch view](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens#branches-view-), but also forces the bottom left VSCode toolbar widget (the `Status Bar Sync`) to refresh itself more often.

I usually have to wait a few seconds when switching back to VSCode before its status refreshed correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the response. So your response tells me that my expectation is reasonable i.e. the status bar should reflect the branch, albeit with some apparent lag. I already have the GitLens plugin installed (sorry - should have mentioned that) but haven't yet see the status bar update when I change branch. I will take another look though (wait a bit longer, perhaps).

Comment: By the way, can I ask what the expectation is for files that are open? If I have File1 open while BranchA is checkout, then checkout BranchB (which has a different version of File1) what can I / should I do to make sure I am editing the correct version. My assumption here is that I will be editing the original version (for BranchA) unless I explicitly close the editor window and reopen it (for BranchB). But that's not clear to me so any suggestions here would be appreciated.

Comment: A quick note that, with GitLens installed as usual, my status bar never refreshes. I checked out a different branch, went away and did some stuff and 15 minutes later the status bar was unchanged. I am not sure if that is what you meant by "I have to wait a few seconds when switching back to VSCode before its status refreshed correctly". The only time I have ever seen this correct (after a checkout) is by closing and reopening VS.Code.

Comment: @MarkWilliams I meant switching back from another window/application back to VSCode.

Comment: @MarkWilliams Regarding switching branch, if a file is being modified, the branch switch will fail. You would need to stash first or commit, before switching branch.

Comment: That's strange - I am not seeing the status bar refresh under any circumstances, including just switching windows. Also, I just edited a file (no stash or commit) but was able to issue a git checkout to another branch (without error). Interestingly, the git checkout command reported a change ('M")  to the fle I changed, but it let me switch. I confirmed that by closing down VS.Code and I was in the new branch.

Comment: Just to add to my confusion (I fear I am missing some fundamental point here somehow)... I edited, let's say, File1 while in BranchA. I then did "git checkout branchb" (no error). I then closed down VS.Code and reopened it. The editor shows the (non-stashed/committed) change I made while in BranchA. Even if I close that window and re-open it (while now in BranchB) I still see the change I made in BranchA.

Comment: @MarkWilliams Is your modified file already tracked, or is it a new one? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38880083/6309.

Comment: Yes, already tracked (my main WordPress plugin file, so I am just updating the version for this test). For example, I am in my "main" branch and change the version number to "3.20". Then save file (no stash/commit) that and switch to another branch (no errors doing that). The original editor window is still visible (I assume that is by design) and shows "3.20". I close that window and re-open the file and see "3.20". So I can't see how/where I can edit the file that is in the current branch. This is a good discussion since this confused me for a long time :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239986/discussion-between-vonc-and-mark-williams).